Cannot Find Asset error AWS Lambda Stack even when the directory to the asset looks fine
Image of directory I was trying to deploy a lambda stack that contains a lambda function. The code that the function will run lies in a services folder under the source folder. I run into a cannot find asset error even when the directory to my file seems to be correct in the lambda function. Does anyone know what I am missing?
import { Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import {
  Code,
  Function as LambdaFunction,
  Runtime,
} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { join } from "path";

export class LambdaStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new LambdaFunction(this, "getBooksLambda", {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      handler: "getBooks.main",
      code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, "..", "..", "services", "getBooks")),
    });
  }
}


exports.main = async function(event, context) {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: "Hello from Lambda"
        })
    }
}

Error: Cannot find asset at C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\src\services\getBooks
    at new AssetStaging (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\asset-staging.js:1:2119)
    at new Asset (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-s3-assets\lib\asset.js:1:1141)
    at AssetCode.bind (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\code.js:5:3487)
    at new Function (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\function.js:1:10003)
    at new LambdaStack (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\src\infra\stacks\LambdaStack.ts:13:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\src\infra\Launcher.ts:12:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\User\Documents\Bookeroo\bookeroo-cdk\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)

I just tried running it expecting the cdk synth to not throw an error. I also tried moving around the getBooks file and also adding .js to the end of the directory. None of them worked

Did the answer work?

According to the docs, Code.fromAsset accepts Either a directory with the Lambda code bundle or a .zip file.
Change the path you're passing to be the folder containing the asset (i.e. remove "getBooks")
